# Generate combinations of length k from number set N, order matters, replacement allowed

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, combinatorics, python-itertools

I would like to generate combinations of length k, from a set of N numbers, where order matters and numbers can be replaced. For example if k = 3, and N = [1, 2, 3], then candidate outputs would include, for example, (1, 1, 1), (2, 2, 2), (3, 2, 1), (1, 2, 3).

I believe I'm nearly there with the following code

```
x = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(1,4),3)
```

But this gives results where order does not matter - i.e it thinks (1, 2, 3) is the same as (3, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1) etc etc.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Do you care about having twice the same output ? Do you need it to be random ?

Comment: Permutations do not repeat elements.

Comment: It sounds like you want the Cartesian product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

N = [1, 2, 3]

y = list(itertools.product(N, N))
print(y)  # [(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
          #             ^               ^
          #             |_______________| he no longer thinks it's the same
```

Now, from your question it is not clear what you would like to do if `k != len(N)` so I will leave that to you (slice `N` maybe?)..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import itertools
x = [1, 2, 3]
list(itertools.product(x, repeat=3))
```

Comment: Just puts it in a list. Probably better to do it with list(itertools.product(x, repeat=3)), editing that now

Comment: In recent versions of Python you can do it with `[*itertools.product(x, repeat=3)]`